# Trying to use net use and shutdown.exe command ERROR

Tags: windows-8.1, batch-file, shutdown, net-use

Have three computers all part of the same workgroup so no domain. Two computers running Windows 8.1 Pro and the third computer is running Windows 10 Pro. I'm executing a batch file from one of the two Windows 8.1 computer trying to shutdown the other Windows 8.1 computer. I followed the steps shown at the following [link](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/remote-shutdown-restart-windows-10/).

Trying to use the following commands to shutdown a Windows 8.1 computer using a batch file.

```
net use \\XFL-DEVS\IPC$   password!   /USER:vmehra
shutdown.exe /s /m \\XFL-DEVS /t 10
```

Get the following error(s) right after the net use command

**System error 1326 has occurred.
The user name or password is incorrect.**

Get the following error(s) after the shutdown command
**xfl-devs: Access is denied.(5)**

Comment: `/USER:vmehra` assumes your local user whereas you need to specify the user from the remote system.

Answer (score 0):

See the Microsoft article
[Restart or Shut Down a Remote Computer and Document the Reason](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc770416(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#using-a-command-line)
on the requirements for remote shutdown.

The complete syntax of the command is:

```
shutdown /[r|s] /m \\**ComputerName /c "Comment" /d [u|p] <xx>:<yy>
```

See the article for the explanation of the arguments.

Some important remarks:

- Membership in the Administrators group, or equivalent, on the remote computer is the minimum required to complete this procedure
- The Remote Registry service must be enabled on the remote computer for Shutdown Event Tracker to record information
- To shut down or restart a remote computer, the Remote Administration and Windows Management Instrumentation firewall exceptions must be enabled on the remote computer.

Comment: Latest documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown